# Why doesn't the graph display a new branch branching off from the master branch, when I create a new branch in terminal?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

Why doesn't the graph in Sourcetree display a new branch branching off from the master branch , when I create a new branch called "testing123" in terminal ?

Sourcetree recognises the new branch but it doesn't branch off from the master branch in the graph. Why is this happening ? How can I make Sourcetree graph display the new branch branching off from master?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It does: it has one new commit done from `master`.

That means you have checked out the new branch `testing123`, done one commit and pushed it (hence origin/`testing123`).

You don't see any "branching" because there is no new commit on `master` since `testing123` has been created: the history of `testing123` remains "linear" with the one of `master`.

Once a new commit will have been created on `master`, you will see a fork.

See also [this thread on SourceTree](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/111436/sourcetree-graph-does-not-show-branches):

> 2 possible reasons for this:
>
> 1. You have 'Current Branch' selected at the top of the log view, or
> 2. The branches didn't actually cause a divergence in the graph.
>      A branch is just a marker, unless different commits actually occurred in each that were not shared between then, there won't be a fork in the graph.

Comment: Ahhh. Yes. I just tested it out what you said. You are right. If I make a commit on `master` now, the new branch is displayed.

Comment: It's important to note that the graph view is not a graphical branch view, it's a graphical history view, and the history is currently linear. The branch *is* displayed in your picture, you can see the branch name in those labels, but the history is linear so it doesn't get its own column and thus "veer off" from the main branch.

Answer (score 18):

This is actually a genuine issue if the purpose of GitFlow is to be intuitively informative. If I do an initial commit followed by branch develop, and branch feature1 (as in Vincent Dreissen's [A Successful Git-Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)) GitFlow depicts this as a linear chain o-o-o when in fact it should be a branching chain

```
    o [feature1]
   /
  o [develop]
 /
o [master]
```

with links in different colors, blue pink, and yellow, to indicate that these are three separate branches. Now GitFlow does "fix" this problem when you eventually merge develop and feature, and then merge master and develop, but until you do those merges the graph looks much different than what you are conceptualizing.

Can there be an option to make different branches appear in different colors? Because the original questioner's point is right - the master and test123 branches appear in a single line of a single color. That is actually not quite right, and is very confusing to the noobie.

Comment: I completely agree. Moreover, it should make an effort to ensure long-lived branches maintain the same color and left-right place in the history. It's horrible that `develop` and `master` keep switching places.