# Sourcetree graph only show master branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

When using sourceTree, I have created two branches under the master branch and made a commit and merge operation, but it did not appear on the Graph.
It look like this：
[image]
I mean why it is only show one master branch, not like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The graph clearly shows the `master`, `feature` and `developer` branches. `master` is on the initial commit, `feature` and `developer` are on the most recent commit. Please note their labels in the list, before the commit subjects.

It seems the history of your project never diverged. You created the initial commit (on `master`) then created the `developer` and `feature` branches. They were initially pointing to the same commit as the `master` branch.

You created several commits on the `developer` branch (I guess) then you checked out the `feature` branch and merged the `developer` branch into it. When this happened, the `developer` branch was where it is now and the `feature` branch was on the same commit as the `master` branch.

Because the `feature` branch (the merge target) was several commits behind the `developer` branch (the merge source) and it didn't contain any commit that was not already in the merge source branch, Git was able to ["fast-forward"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge) the `feature` branch to reach the `developer` branch. There was no need to create a new commit.

"Fast-forward" is the default merging strategy and Git uses it whenever it is possible (when the merge target branch is an ancestor of the merge source branch). You can force it to create a merge commit (and ignore the "fast-forward" strategy) by adding `--no-ff` in the [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) command line. If you use a GUI Git client look for a *"No fast-forward"* checkbox in the Git merge dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any "master branch" because there is not new commit on that branch. See [Why doesn't the graph display a new branch branching off from the master branch, when I create a new branch in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215383/why-doesnt-the-graph-display-a-new-branch-branching-off-from-the-master-branch) for details.